Calendar alerts have stopped
I'm running Sequoia 15.0.1. Lately none of my Calendar alerts have been firing. I haven't made any changes to my Calendar or Notification settings. In Notifications->Calendar I have the following settings

Allow notifications on
Notification style Alerts
Allow time sensitive alerts on
Show notifications on lock screen on
Badge application icon off
Show in Notification Center on
Play sound for notification on
Show previews Default
Notification grouping Automatic

This may have started after I installed the 15.0.1 update. But I don't remember how many days there were between 15.0 and 15.0.1, I might not have had any events that took place between them. I'm certain my alerts were working before Sequoia.
This seems to be affecting only my pre-existing events. I created a new test event and the notification showed up.
Any idea what I need to do to get my notifications back? Do I need to recreate all my events?
It's not affecting Reminder alerts, even though they've been integrated into Calendar.

Alerts are working again.
I haven't made any changes to settings. The only thing I can guess is that creating the test event cleared up whatever blockage there might have been.
So if anyone else runs into this problem, try creating a new event and then delete it after the notification occurs.
